# ASP.NET - Giving Session object a value by its index raises error

Tags: asp.net, session-state

When I write:

```
Session["conString"]= theConString;
```

It works perfectly. but if I try to write:

```
Session[0] = the ConString;
```

I get "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection" error. I understand that this is a typical error to arrays. It means I'm trying to set value of an object that does not exist. But, how come I can do it by specifying the name for the session object. There are to ways to do so: 1Giving a string name or numeric index. I need this option because on other pages I don't want to have to memorize the string names, instead I want to declare global constants and access them using those constant names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container for the session has a length of 0 when initialized, so you are trying to set the value of an element that does not exist yet. Whereas using a named key will resize the container as needed.

Comment: Hmm, so there's a special credit given to the way of using named key. So it does something like Session.Add("conString",theConString) right? Then specifying named key turns out to be a shortcut to that method.

Comment: I now remember that I can declare string constants too.

Comment: Essentially, yes. IMHO, the positional indexer on Session is kind of silly and has a code smell to it, but I suppose there might be some reason to enumerate through items by index and perhaps replace them. Anyways, in the practical world you'll only ever need to get/set session items using a key.